# MDX Where vs SubCube Confusion

Tags: ssas, mdx, olap

I have the following MDX:

```
SELECT NON EMPTY 
       {
            [Measures].[My Measure]
       } ON COLUMNS 
FROM 
(
    SELECT 
           NONEMPTY(StrToMember(@StartDate,CONSTRAINED):StrToMember(@EndDate,CONSTRAINED)) 
           ON COLUMNS,

           NONEMPTY( STRTOSET(@Division)) 
           ON ROWS
    FROM
    (
        SELECT 
               NONEMPTY({[Project].[Project Status].&[Open],[Project].[Project Status].&[Closed]}) 
               ON COLUMNS,

               NONEMPTY(STRTOSET(@TargetLanguage)) 
               ON ROWS
        FROM [My Cube]
    )
    WHERE STRTOSET(@Project)
)
WHERE STRTOSET(@Requestor)
```

**My goal is the following:**  Filter on @StartDate,@EndDate,@Division,@TargetLanguage,@Project,@Requestor (in addition to filtering project status to open/closed...)

They only way I can ever get these to work is by playing around with sub cubes and axes until I get a result that appears right...  Here for example, I don't understand why, in the second subselect, I can't simply put a:

```
Where STRTOSET(@TargetLanguage)
```

instead of putting that on rows.  I cannot be 100% sure that this is returning the correct data because it is so convuluted... Any explanation?  Google has thus-far been unhelpful, which leads me to believe that putting things on rows in subcubes is not the right solution...

Thanks!

Comment: I will definitively build only 1 subcube putting sets and dimension on1, on2, on3 and more axes. It will be a clear and quick mdx query.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

I'm not 100% with sub cubes but refactoring your code I think it's the same as:

```
SELECT NON EMPTY 
       {
            [Measures].[My Measure]
       } ON COLUMNS 
FROM 
       [My Cube]
WHERE 
(
    STRTOSET(@Requestor),
    STRTOSET(@TargetLanguage), 
    {[Project].[Project Status].&[Open],[Project].[Project Status].&[Closed]},
    STRTOSET(@Division),
    {StrToMember(@StartDate,CONSTRAINED):StrToMember(@EndDate,CONSTRAINED)},
    STRTOSET(@TargetLanguage)
)
```

And to tell you the truth the first non empty doesn't seem to be needed either.

The way I see it is that inner sub cubes are just filtering slices and I think they are pretty simple enough to add to that main filter.